# Getting multiple JSON objects in Python from API with max 100 records

Tags: python, airtable

I am using Airtable to get some records and I have issues getting all the records I have.

Airtable limits you to 100 records per API call, so if the records are more than 100, they give you an offset field in the results.

What I need to do is to call the API, check if the offset is there, if it's the case, make another call using this offset, and at the end, get all the data and merge them into one single JSON dictionnary.

No matter what I do, I don't get the objects I need, so maybe I have an issue in my code, that I couldn't notice:

Here is the function to make the call:

```
def get_all(table):
    url = f"{endpoint}/{table}"
    r = requests.get(url = url, headers = headers)
    return r.json()
```

And here is the function to make the call using an offset:

```
def get_all_w_offset(table, offset):
    url = f"{endpoint}/{table}"
    r = requests.get(url = url, headers = headers, params={'offset': offset})
    return r.json()
```

And this is the function that needs to collect all objects from the API:

```
def get_all_advances():
    rsp = get_all(REGISTRE_TBL)  # get all registry items
    data = json.loads(json.dumps(rsp))  # convert our items into json format

    while True:
        data = json.loads(json.dumps(rsp))
        records = data.get("records", [])
        offset = data.get("offset")
        if not offset:
            return records
        else:
            rsp = get_all_w_offset(REGISTRE_TBL, offset)
            data = json.loads(json.dumps(rsp))
```

But I do not get all the objects I have on Airtable.

I use a similar way in another function and it works with no issues, I copied the same code and did not work, that is why I changed it and still, does not work. Let me show you the function that actually works:

```
def validateUser(cin, tphone):
    data = get_all(EMPLOYEES_TBL)
    data = json.loads(json.dumps(data))
    cin = cin.upper()
    try:
        offset = data["offset"]
    except KeyError:
        offset = None

    while offset:
        for i in data["records"]:
            try:
                if tphone == i["fields"]["Téléphone"] and cin == i["fields"]["CIN"]:
                    return i
                else:
                    continue
            except KeyError:
                continue
        data = get_all_w_offset(EMPLOYEES_TBL, offset)
    return False
```

Comment: This isn't a specific answer but more generally, have you tried to recreate the same API request in a testing tool like Postman? It can help to set up an identical request that you think your python library/logic are making so that you can determine if there is something wrong with the API request/response or with the logic you have in python code. Then, onsider adding the results of your findings to this question to further narrow down your problem.